# Convert Date MMDDYY to Date for database Insert

Tags: c#

I got an array with a date set as `071712` . no / slash characters for the date, no dash. nothing, just plain   `071712` (coming from a text file).

I need to convert the date so I can include it in a SqlServer insert statement. I'm calling a stored procedure for the insert. So far I have this:

```
// This is not working so far.
DateTime  date = Convert.ToDateTime(fileLines[4]);
```

(date will be used as a parm for the stored procedure)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(text, "MMddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Link to the documentation for [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) would be nice also.